# Charge 12 V battery bank from a 24 V MPPT solar charge controller

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller, lifepo4

I am planning on boondocking on my RV and am in the phase of designing the system and want to stay at 12 V. I have found the perfect solar panels for it, but the specs make them somewhat odd to wire:

Quantity: 4 panels
Rated Power (Pmax): 200 W
Voltage at Pmax (Vmp): 63.8V
Current at Pmax (Imp): 3.2A
Short-circuit current (Isc): 4.1 A
Open-circuit voltage (Voc): 96.0 V

I have two 12 V, 200 Ah LiFePO4 batteries in parallel to run my 12 V inverter. To stay in budget I was thinking if it would be OK to have the battery bank wired in series and parallel at same time so I can discharge them at 12 V and charge them at 24 V to increase the power I can run on the same charge controller.

**Edit:**
Something like this example but I think they are charging at 36v a battery bank of 72v
[image]

Comment: You can't wire in series and parallel at the same time - it's not possible.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is boondocking?

Comment: Just get a 24V inverter.

Comment: boondocking is when you camp with your rv without connections like water or electricity

Answer (score 2):

The charge controller on my RV senses the battery voltage upon connection.

And is rated at both 12 and 24V source.

[image: Victron MPPT 75/15]